# How to pause video player in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have viewPager with 3 pages , in one of these pages I have video player. I'm facing a problem that I video player keeps working on all pages. How can i pause video player will changing page ?

Adapter:

```
public class HomeTabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    MainActivity activity;


    public HomeTabsAdapter(MainActivity activity, FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
        this.activity = activity;
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                return VideoTrendsFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return MomytFragment.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return StoryFragment.newInstance();
                default:
                    return MomytFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you don't have access to your player object outside your fragments you can try this method.

The current constructor `HomeTabsAdapter` which extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` you have is deprecated.

So I would encourage you to switch your constructor to the one as below:

```
//Not sure why you need to have activity in you constructor but since currently does
public HomeTabsAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior, MainActivity activity) {
    super(fm, behavior);
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Therefore you'll also have to change the adapter initiation in your activity to something as:

```
adapter = new HomeTabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
```

If you use the above mentioned Behaviour-flag, when the page changes the `onPause` method will be called for that fragment and on returning back to it fragment's `onResume` will be called.

So you need to override those methods in your fragments like :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mPlayer.isPlaying())
          mPlayer.pause();
}
```

If you don't wish to remove the deprecated constructor I don't have a perfect solution, but you can check try checking if page is visible using `if(getUserVisibleHint())` and pause for false. but this check will be needed at regular intervals using a handler perhaps.

Check if this was of any help.

Answer (score -1):

OnPause of fragment check like this -

```
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mPlayer.pause();
    } else {
        mPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get  java.lang.NullPointerException since videoplayer is defined in fragment not in all activity